# UILabel not updating but inherits value

Tags: class, methods, swift3, singleton, uilabel

I am trying to update my `UILabel` that is set up in my ViewController. The update comes from pressing a cell in my collectionView which is another class. The label inherits the value but doesn't update graphically. I suspect this is because a new instance of the view controller is created when pressing the cell, and its not updating the current one.

How can I update the UIlabel of my current instance?

**ViewController:**

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class mainHomeController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        setupBasketBar()

    }

    let totNumber: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "0"
        label.numberOfLines = 2
        return label
    }()

    func updateBarText() {
        totNumber.text = "Update"
    }

    func setupBasketBar() {

        self.view.addSubview(totNumber)
        totNumber.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        totNumber.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor,constant: 330).isActive = true
        totNumber.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        totNumber.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor,constant: 0).isActive = true
        totNumber.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor,multiplier: 5).isActive = true


    }

}
```

the function that triggers the action (**collectionView class**):

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {


    mainHomeController().updateBarText()
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've implemented `collection​View:​did​Select​Item​At​Index​Path:​` in `mainHomeController`, you can replace `mainHomeController().updateBarText()` with `updateBarText()`.